# Aligning a sample resume

Tags: horizontal-alignment, resume

I have two questions:

1. How do you edit the tex file so that "Contact information" and "DEPT" are aligned horizontally?
2. What do you need to edit so that "Education" isn't cut off to the left of the paper? I'm not using a4 paper but I'm using a standard 8.5 x 11 inches paper.

`resume.cls` can be found at http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/files/p54-resume/resume.cls

I'm using this photo also: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/BallonKathedrale01_edit.jpg

Although the picture is fairly big, isn't there a way so that the left column stays on the page? Please save the picture as "hot-air-balloon" in order for tex to compile.

Thanks.

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{resume}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[english,danish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, a4paper=true, pdfstartview=FitV,
linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\pdfcompresslevel=9


\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}



    \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{0.20in}
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{0.20in}
    \addtolength{\textwidth}{-0.45in}

    \addtolength{\topmargin}{.5in}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{-1.75in}



\catcode`~=11  
\newcommand{\urltilde}{\kern -.15em\lower .7ex\hbox{~}\kern .04em}
\catcode`~=13  




\begin{document}

\lfoot{LEFT}
\cfoot{CENTER}
\rfoot{\thepage \hspace{10mm}}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}




{\sc \Large \bf  NAME HERE}
\begin{resume}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.6\textwidth}
        \vspace{-1cm}
       \begin{center}
       \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{hot-air-balloon}
       \end{center}
        \vspace{-1cm}  
    \end{wrapfigure}   


    \section{\mysidestyle \color{red} \bf Contact\\ information}%\vspace{2mm}
    DEPT \\ 
    PHONE: 123-456-7890 \\


    \section{\mysidestyle\color{red} \bf Education}    
    \textbf{SOME DEGREE from SOME SCHOOL.}   MORE DETAILED INFORMATION WILL BE MENTIONED HERE. 

  \end{resume} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Can you add a link to the document class as well, `resume.cls` isn't on CTAN as far as I can tell.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sorry for the delay but I found the link: http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/files/p54-resume/resume.cls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't delve into the class to explore why, but I could fix the problem using two things:  first, I used `\textcolor{red}{...}` instead of `\color{red}...`; and secondly, I treated `\mysidestyle` as if it was expecting an argument (even though it doesn't), and enclosed what followed in braces.

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{resume}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[english,danish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, a4paper=true, pdfstartview=FitV,
linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\pdfcompresslevel=9


\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}



    \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{0.20in}
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{0.20in}
    \addtolength{\textwidth}{-0.45in}

    \addtolength{\topmargin}{.5in}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{-1.75in}

\catcode`~=11  
\newcommand{\urltilde}{\kern -.15em\lower .7ex\hbox{~}\kern .04em}
\catcode`~=13  

\begin{document}

\lfoot{LEFT}
\cfoot{CENTER}
\rfoot{\thepage \hspace{10mm}}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

{\sc \Large \bf  NAME HERE}
\begin{resume}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.6\textwidth}
        \vspace{-1cm}
       \begin{center}
       \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{hot-air-balloon}
       \end{center}
        \vspace{-1cm}  
    \end{wrapfigure}   

    \section{\mysidestyle{\textcolor{red}{\bf Contact\\ information}}}
    DEPT \\ 
    PHONE: 123-456-7890 \\


    \section{\mysidestyle{\textcolor{red}{\bf Education}}}
    \textbf{SOME DEGREE from SOME SCHOOL.}   MORE DETAILED INFORMATION WILL BE MENTIONED HERE. 

  \end{resume} 
\end{document}
```

[image]